# Windows NTLM authentication using Node.js + Express

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, active-directory, ntlm

I'm building a Node.js + Express microservice running on Ubuntu to communicate with Windows NTLM protected REST service. I'm using https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm as http client.

It has been giving me nuts in the last couple of days trying to authenticate. Do you think password-less Windows account and/or addition of Active Directory may be the issue here?

As mentioned, I'm using httpntlm to fire requests. I have a piece of code like this:

```
try {
    httpntlm.method(method, {
        url: requestUrl,
        username: config.exact.username,
        password: config.exact.password,
        domain: config.exact.domain,
        headers:{
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'ServerName': '',
            'DatabaseName': '',
        },
    }, callback);
} catch (e) {
    return response.status(500);
}
```

whereas `config.exact.password` is empty. I tried to either pass domain as domain parameter or directly within username (as `DOMAIN\username`). All of that ends up as 401 response though.

Problem here, in my opinion, is that Windows where I have that service running is connected via Active Directory therefore there are no passwords on Windows accounts. Have you experienced anything like this stack before?